# BigQuery very slow CSV upload

Tags: csv, upload, insert, stream, google-bigquery

BigQuery suddenly slowed 2019-02-26 16:00 UTC by about 10x for CSV upload to replace an existing table through API.

What would cause this sudden uptick in upload time? What once took 30min is now taking 6 hours.

Comment: Check your process execution time maybe you Exceeded your project slot limit?

Comment: for debugging please use the BigQuery issue tracker and make sure to include a job id

Comment: @TamirKlein How can I check this?

Answer (score 0):

Since your question is a general one let me give you some guidelines on how to continue.
You can find the execution plan in the webUI near the results or from the Job history on the top left panel, See an image below on how to open the execution plan of a query.

Important notes:

1. You see 4 colours phases which show the execution lifetime, If the Wait phase is coloured and not greyed out it means you are waiting for a resource
2. output of a phase is the input of the 2nd phase, So if your output is big it might mean the next step is working hard to finish, There are few best practice around this which can be described per a specific issue

[image]

3. You can also expand the step and see more interesting details such as: Shuffeling, Broadcast, Sort etc which can help you get more information on what's going on under the hood

[image]

4. This is [BigQuery URL](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/query-plan-explanation) with more details on execution plan (Check to [Job.get](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest/v2/jobs/get) API to get this the execution plan via API)
5. This is [BigQuery Limit](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/quotas) information

Comment: @Michael, hope my answer was helpful, note: important on SO - you can mark accepted answer by using the tick on the left of the posted answer, below the voting. See [meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work#5235) for why it is important